# calculating width of utf8 string rendered by free type

Tags: c, word-wrap, freetype, glyph, freetype2

I rendered a utf8 presentation B string (e.g. `"\xef\xbb\x9d\xef\xba\x8e\xef\xaf\xbe\xef\xba\xad\x20"`) using freetype, and for alignment calculating I need to retrieve width of glyphs of the rendered string.
this is my code and seems obtained value for width is not valid. then whats problem and how i could calculate exact width parameter of the rendered string without using Harfbuzz or any other  higher level library ?

```
    size_t        len = utf8strlen( text);

    FT_Library    library;
    FT_Face       face;

    FT_GlyphSlot  slot;
    FT_Error      error;

    int row     = 0;
    int wdt   = 0;
    int pch   = 0;

    error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );              /* initialize library */

    error = FT_New_Face( library, "font.ttf", 0, &face );/* create face object */

    error = FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes( face, 52, 24 );

    for ( size_t cntr = 0; cntr < len; cntr++ )
    {

        /* load glyph image into the slot (erase previous one) */
        error = FT_Load_Char( face, text[cntr], FT_LOAD_RENDER );
        if ( error )
          continue;                 /* ignore errors */


        // draw glyph image anti-aliased
        FT_Render_Glyph( face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL );
        // get dimensions of bitmap
        row     += face->glyph->bitmap.rows;
        wdt     += face->glyph->bitmap.width;
        pch     += face->glyph->bitmap.pitch;

    }
```

Comment: The horizontal space occupied by the string is not necessarily equal to the sum of the horizontal space occupied by each glyph; for example, in most fonts **Tej** is shorter than **T** plus **e** plus **j**.

Comment: You need to account for kerning (and keming).

Comment: Thank for replies, Reading Free type 2 documents, seems I does not consider Kerning.I will read and improve my code.

Comment: in (at least) 3 statements the variable `error` is being set, but the code fails to check the resulting value (at each statement where `error` is being set) to assure the statement was successful and if not successful, then to pass an appropriate error message (via `stderr`) to the user